# Regarding regular expressions and case conversion using Qt

Tags: regex, qt

I'm working on a Qt based software that involves some cryptography. The only three hashing algorithms used are specified as

```
SHA-256
MD5
SHA
```

However, the API that i am using requires them to be in the form of

```
sha256
md5
sha
```

respectively. 
Even though I can write a messy function to somehow get things done, I know this can be simplified with the regular expression support in Qt. Please help me come up with a regular expression that does this task of conversion.

This is what I am doing now

```
if (hashType == QString("SHA")) {
        return QString("sha");
    }
    else if (hashType == QString("MD5")) {
        return QString("md5");
    }
    else if (hashType == QString("SHA-256")) {
        return QString("sha256");
    }
    else {
        return hashType;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say using a regex is overkill for this.  You just need:

```
return hashType.remove('-').toLower();
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can achieve a simpler code with regexp, since replacing is done by calling `QString::replace()`  For me the cleanest method you could use is QMap (`value` returns second argument if an object is not found in the map).

```
 QMap<QString, QString> replacements;
 replacements["SHA"] = "sha";
 replacements["MD5"] = "md5";
 ....

 return replacements.value(hashType, hashType);
```